Is this a secure PRF?
Let $F:\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ be a secure PRF. Consider a construction of a new PRF $F':\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ as follows $F'_{k}(x)=F_{F_{k}(x)}(x)$. Is $F'$ secure?
Solution: I was trying to prove it secure by hybrid argument. I constructed three hybrids as follows:
Hybrid $H_0:F'_k(x)=F_{F_{k}(x)}(x)$
Hybrid $H_1:F'_k(x)=F_{TRF(x)}(x)$ and
Hybrid $H_2:F'_k(x)=TRF(x)$
To show: $H_0$ and $H_2$ are computationally indistinguishable.
It is sufficient to show the following:
(a) $H_0$ and $H_1$ are computationally indistinguishable and
(b) $H_1$ and $H_2$ are computationally indistinguishable.
I have shown that $H_0$ and $H_1$ are computationally indistinguishable. But I am not able how to show that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are computationally indistinguishable.

you've asked another similar question, it seems you have an assignment with variations on a theme. strictly soeaking that is fine but it would help to show your work. You say "I have shown...". How? Give context

Also I guess TRF is truely random function? Write it out.

No... It's not part of any assignment. To show $H_1$ is computationally indistinguishable to $H_2$ is easy. Like if you have an adversary who can distinguish between $H_0$ and $H_1$ with significant probability, then using it as a subroutine one can construct an efficient distinguisher for the PRF $F$.
